# Javascript Animation(Canvas) not working in firefox, Edge but works on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a code from codepen. I am trying to work on this one. This code works on chrome but does not work in firefox or edge. I tried to solve the issue but could not fix it. Is the problem with requestAnimationFrame or something else? Can anyone please help? Here is the codepen link: https://codepen.io/iremlopsum/pen/MKNaxd

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("#scene"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    particles = [],
    amount = 0,
    mouse = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    radius = 0.7; //Init radius of the force field

var colors = ["rgba(255,255,255, .6)", "rgba(255,255,255, .6)", "rgba(255,255,255, .6)", "rgba(255,255,255, .6)", "rgba(255,255,255, .6)", "rgba(255,255,255, .6)"];

var colorsTwo = ["rgba(255,255,255, .6)", "rgba(255,255,255, .6)", "rgba(255,255,255, .6)", "rgba(255,255,255, .6)", "rgba(255,255,255, .6)", "rgba(255,255,255, .6)"];

var copy = "Mighty Byte"; // Text to display

var initSize = Math.floor(Math.random() * .6) + 1  ;
var hoverSize = initSize + .7;

var ww = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
var wh = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

function Particle(x, y) {
    this.x = Math.random() * ww;
    this.y = Math.random() * wh;
    this.dest = {
        x: x,
        y: y
    };
    //this.r = Math.random() * 1; // the size of bubbles
    this.vx = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2;
    this.vy = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2;
    this.accX = 0;
    this.accY = 0;
    this.friction = Math.random() * 0.015 + 0.94; // force of bounce, just try to change 0.015 to 0.5

    //this.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)];  
    //this.colorTwo = colorsTwo[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)];

}

Particle.prototype.render = function() {

    this.accX = (this.dest.x - this.x) / 200; //acceleration for X
    this.accY = (this.dest.y - this.y) / 200; //acceleration for Y
    this.vx += this.accX;
    this.vy += this.accY;
    this.vx *= this.friction;
    this.vy *= this.friction;

    this.x += this.vx;
    this.y += this.vy;

    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.fill();

    var a = this.x - mouse.x;
    var b = this.y - mouse.y;

    var distance = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
    if (distance < (radius * 70)) {
        this.accX = (this.x - mouse.x) / 20; //acceleration on mouseover X, smaller faster
        this.accY = (this.y - mouse.y) / 20; //acceleration on mouseover Y, smaller faster
        this.vx += this.accX;
        this.vy += this.accY;
        //ctx.fillStyle = this.colorTwo;
    }

    if (distance < (radius * 70)) {
        this.colorTwo = colorsTwo[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)];
        ctx.fillStyle = this.colorTwo;
        this.r = hoverSize; // the size of bubbles
    }

    if (distance > (radius * 70)) {
        this.colorOne = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)];
        ctx.fillStyle = this.colorOne;
        this.r = initSize
    }

}

function onMouseMove(e) {
    mouse.x = e.clientX;
    mouse.y = e.clientY;
}

function initScene() {
    ww = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    wh = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.font = "bold " + (ww / 10) + "px sans-serif"; // Size of the text
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText(copy, ww / 2, wh / 2); //Centering

    var data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ww, wh).data;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "screen";

    particles = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < ww; i += Math.round(ww / 400)) { //400 here represents the amount of particles
        for (var j = 0; j < wh; j += Math.round(ww / 400)) {
            if (data[((i + j * ww) * 4) + 3] > 250) {
                particles.push(new Particle(i, j));
            }
        }
    }
    amount = particles.length;

}

function onMouseClick() {
    radius = 4; //onclick expand radius

}

function offMouseClick() {
    radius = 0.5; //offClick init radius
}

function delayedInitRadius() {
    setTimeout(offMouseClick, 500); //delay for offClick init radius
}

function render(a) {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        particles[i].render();
    }
};

window.addEventListener("resize", initScene);
window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
window.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseClick);
window.addEventListener("mouseup", delayedInitRadius);
initScene();
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

Comment: It works on firefox for me, It's just hideously slow. The pen took 30 seconds to load and seems to run at 2 seconds a frame on firefox. same story on edge.

Comment: Its not working here. I tried with several laptops. Any idea what might be the issue or what is slowing it down? I read in several blogs that "requestAnimationFrame" does not work properly in firefox

Comment: I believe it's an issue of browser performance, because firefox works fine, but it's very slow. But, you _are_ spawning 400 * 400 (160 000) particles. I would try reducing this number if I were you

Comment: I reduced the particles to 200 (200*200) but both the firefox and edge take huge time to render. Its a bit faster then before but still way below the par :(

Comment: Let's continue this conversation here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182319/speed-up-particle-rendering

Comment: The code in your jsbin example runs 18fps @ 1366x553 in Chrome and runs at about 1/2 the speed in an IE 11 window that's about 50% larger (so about 75% the speed) Have you considered using WebGL? I imagine you'll be able to use even more of the platform's hardware to your advantage.

Comment: That sounds like it could work, but judging by the level of his/her profile, I doubt this person has the know-how. Correct me if I'm wrong, but WebGL isn't the easiest thing to implement.