# Javascript text particle in canvas slow in firefox but not on chrome (requestAnimationFrame ?)

Tags: javascript, canvas, requestanimationframe

I'm struggling with the implementation of a text particle in javascript.

My code is working fine with chromium-based browsers (Chromium: 84) but is unexpectedly slow on firefox (79.0).
I've searched a lot, but still don't find a solution and where the problem is.(This is pretty much linked to this [Javascript Animation(Canvas) not working in firefox, Edge but works on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52942172/javascript-animationcanvas-not-working-in-firefox-edge-but-works-on-chrome)).

Here is my codepen:
https://codepen.io/jgazeau/pen/LYNYPYB

```
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}
function getCssVar(v) {
  return getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue(v);
}

let text404 = '404';
let canvas = document.getElementById('scene');
let ch = canvas.height = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().height;
let cw = canvas.width = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().width;
let sceneBackground = getCssVar('--scene-background');
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
let previousMouseCoord = {x:0, y:0};
let mouseCoord = {x:0, y:0};
let sceneResize = false;
let particlesCount = 0;
let particles = [];
let colors = [
  getCssVar('--particle-color-1'),
  getCssVar('--particle-color-2'),
  getCssVar('--particle-color-3'),
  getCssVar('--particle-color-4'),
  getCssVar('--particle-color-5')
];
const dpi = 200;

let Particle = function(x, y) {
  this.x =  getRandomInt(cw);
  this.y =  getRandomInt(ch);
  this.coord = {x:x, y:y};
  this.r =  Math.min((getRandomInt((cw / dpi)) + 1), 6);
  this.vx = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 100;
  this.vy = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 100;
  this.accX = 0;
  this.accY = 0;
  this.friction = Math.random() * 0.05 + 0.90;
  this.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)];
}

Particle.prototype.render = function(isDisableMouse) {
  this.accX = (this.coord.x - this.x) / 100;
  this.accY = (this.coord.y - this.y) / 100;
  this.vx += this.accX;
  this.vy += this.accY;
  this.vx *= this.friction;
  this.vy *= this.friction;
  this.x += this.vx;
  this.y +=  this.vy;
  if (!isDisableMouse) {
    let a = this.x - mouseCoord.x;
    let b = this.y - mouseCoord.y;
    var distance = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
    if(distance < (cw / 15)) {
      this.accX = (this.x - mouseCoord.x) / 100;
      this.accY = (this.y - mouseCoord.y) / 100;
      this.vx += this.accX;
      this.vy += this.accY;
    }
  }
  context.fillStyle = this.color;
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();
}

function onmouseCoordMove(e) {
  mouseCoord.x = e.clientX;
  mouseCoord.y = e.clientY;
}

function onTouchMove(e) {
  if(e.touches.length > 0 ) {
    mouseCoord.x = e.touches[0].clientX;
    mouseCoord.y = e.touches[0].clientY;
  }
}

function onTouchEnd() {
  mouseCoord.x = -9999;
  mouseCoord.y = -9999;
}

function initScene() {
  ch = canvas.height = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  cw = canvas.width = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.font = 'bold ' + (cw / 5) + 'px sans-serif';
  context.fillStyle = sceneBackground;
  context.textAlign = 'center';
  context.fillText(text404, cw / 2, ch / 2);
  let imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, cw, ch).data;
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.globalCompositeOperation = 'screen';
  particles = [];
  for(let y = 0; y < ch; y += Math.round(cw / dpi)) {
    for(let x = 0; x < cw; x += Math.round(cw / dpi)) {
      if(imageData[((x + y * cw) * 4) + 3] > 128){
        particles.push(new Particle(x, y));
      }
    }
  }
  particlesCount = particles.length;
}

function renderScene() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  let isDisableMouse = false;
  if ((previousMouseCoord.x === mouseCoord.x) && (previousMouseCoord.x === mouseCoord.x)) {
    isDisableMouse = true;
  } else {
    previousMouseCoord.x = mouseCoord.x;
    previousMouseCoord.x = mouseCoord.x;
    isDisableMouse = false;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < particlesCount; i++) {
    particles[i].render(isDisableMouse);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(renderScene);
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  initScene();
  renderScene();
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', onmouseCoordMove);
  window.addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove);
  window.addEventListener('touchend', onTouchEnd);
  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    if (!sceneResize) {
      requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        initScene();
        sceneResize = false;
      });
      sceneResize = true;
    }
  });
});
```

Can anyone know where this slow issue could come from ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: _"Can anyone know where this slow issue could come from ?"_ - That's a question for your browser. Check the "Performance" tab in the developer tools.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I am able to reproduce the problem, but probably it's not the entire script that's responsible for the slowdown, so this doesn't appear to be a [mcve]. Try to strip parts out of the script until they run at the same speed, then re-add parts until they don't until you've minimized it. Until then, not enough research has been done. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed it comes from the Particle.prototype.render function which only calculate new coordinates to the particle and then render it. The rendering (context.fill()) is giving this slow on firefox. On chrome this fill function is taking 2.5ms to be executed while on firefox it takes around 55ms.

Comment: Your use of `closePath` is completely redundant and has no effect on rendering. Check the size of the arc, anything below 2 pixel radius will look much the same as a `rect` and rects are many times quicker. Sort particles by color, Use only one `beginPath` / `fill` per color (many points per path) to reduce state changes. These will not change FF rendering speed difference, but will greatly increase performance on all browsers

Comment: Thanks @Blindman67,
I test it, and changed the code to only fill the context once and also use the moveTo function (https://codepen.io/jgazeau/pen/RwawgoR). The performances are now much greater on FF, but still laggy. Maybe a browser issue when rendering canvas, but I can't find information about that.